# Common Lisp references to functions

Tags: function, lambda, common-lisp

There seems to be a number of different ways of referring to a function in Common Lisp:

1. via symbol, where the symbol appears (unquoted) as the car of a form as in `(1+ 2) => 3`, or in a functional argument position as in `(mapcar '1+ '(1 2 3)) => (2 3 4)`;
2. via function object, where the (interpreted or compiled) function object can appear in functional argument position as in `(mapcar #'1+ '(1 2 3)) => (2 3 4)` or `(mapcar (symbol-function '1+) '(1 2 3)) => (2 3 4)`, but not as the car of a form as in `(#'1+ 2) => error` or `((symbol-function '1+) 2) => error`;
3. via lambda expression, where the lambda expression appears as the car of a lambda form as in `((lambda (x) (1+ x)) 2) => 3`, or in a functional argument position as in `(mapcar (lambda (x) (1+ x)) '(1 2 3)) => (2 3 4)` [However, the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/26_glo_f.htm) does not recognize lambda expression as a "function designator"].

Of these three "ways", to me the first seems somewhat out of place, because it seems to complicate the fundamental guideline that Common Lisp operators evaluate their arguments only once. And if, in the example above, `'1+` is evaluated, it would produce the symbol `1+`, not the function named by the symbol. In this case, there must be an additional evaluation, possibly `symbol-function`, to get at the function object.  Evidently, this is simply a convenience, but it seems to break with consistency. (The consistent form `#'1+` is almost as simple.) My question is 'Are there any examples where using a symbol for a function is required (other than as the car of a form--although even this is not required, given lambda expressions), so that you cannot fully avoid expressions as in item 1 above?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Symbols as names for objects: Designators**

Often symbols are names for objects and can be used instead of these objects.

The concept that something like a symbol (or a string, a character) may stand for something else is called in Common Lisp a [*designator*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/01_dae.htm).

Some example for *designators*:

Function designator:

```
(funcall 'list 1 2 3)
<->
(funcall (symbol-function 'list) 1 2 3)
```

Class, or symbol that names a class:

```
(make-instance 'my-class)
<->
(make-instance (find-class 'my-class))
```

Package designator:

```
(package-use-list 'cl-user)
<->
(package-use-list (find-package 'cl-user))
<->
(package-use-list "CL-USER")
```

String designator:

```
(string-upcase 'f)
<->
(string-upcase (symbol-name 'f))
<->
(string-upcase #\f)
```

The first argument to `FUNCALL` thus is not defined as a *function*, but as a *function designator*. In this case either a function object or a symbol. If it is a symbol, then the global symbol function is retrieved.

Historically Lisp uses symbols as names for various kinds of objects. This is less prominent in some later dialects or derived languages.

**function object vs. calling a named function vs. calling a symbol function**

```
...(funcall (function foo) 1 2 3)...
...(funcall #'foo 1 2 3)...
```

Above calls the lexical function named `foo`. If there is no lexical function foo, it calls the symbol function of `foo`. The Lisp file compiler may assume that this is the same named function in the same file.

```
...(foo 1 2 3)...
```

Above calls the lexical function named `foo`. If there is no lexical function foo, it calls the symbol function of `foo`. The Lisp file compiler may assume that this is the same named function in the same file.

```
...(funcall 'foo 1 2 3)...
```

Above calls the global symbol function of `foo`. Thus there will be a lookup through the symbol.

Comment: Makes sense. You're pretty good at intuiting the question that I wanted to ask. Also, just realized why a lambda expression is not a function designator--it's a macro! That means coercing a lambda expression into a function object must be redundant, since `(lambda (x) x) => #'(lambda (x) x)`.

Comment: @daypough: (function (lambda ...)) evaluates to a function object. The (lambda ...)  inside (function ...) is the lambda expression.

Comment: A lambda expression, used as an operator, is really a lambda expression.  That is, `((lambda (x) (1+ x)) 1)` will not macro-expand, unlike `(funcall (lambda (x) (1+ x)) 1)`.  It may also affect order of evaluation, i.e. in the `funcall` example, the lambda expression will be evaluated before the other arguments, but in the lambda expression as an operator, it might be evaluated (only once) before or after any of the arguments.

Comment: Perhaps non-obvious: the symbol may be rebound in a FunCall, whereas a function object will not be; so (FunCall 'foo) is the runtime symbol-function of 'Foo, but (FunCall #'Foo) is the compile-time value.

Comment: @BRFennPocock: for lexical scoped functions, but not necessarily for global named functions. The both is possible: using the definition at compile time or a later updated version. For (funcall #'foo).

Comment: @RainerJoswig Your answer is superb.